# determinant proofs

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix.

a.) prove: if $x$ is an $n\times 1$ matrix such that $Ax=0$ then $x=0$.

b.) prove: then $A^{-1}$ is also invertible and $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$

So for a.) I think that because $A$ is invertible, $A^{-1}$ exists if I just multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ then $x=0$ because $A$ will cancel out. I know this to be true if $x$ is an $n\times n$ matrix but I am not sure if that logic holds true when it is an nx1 matrix.

Or b.) I know that matrices aren't integers but all I can see is that if I plug in a number for $A$ then it has to equal $A$ but I know when dealing with matrices that logic cannot be applied. What kind of matrix multiplication is used to obtain this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), (letting $I$ be the identity matrix)

$$x=Ix=(A^{-1}A)x=A^{-1}(Ax)=A^{-1}(0)=0$$

(so yes, what you said works fine even for an $n\times 1$ matrix).

For (b), this really depends what definition of invertible you are working with. Maybe invertible here is defined to mean there exists $B$ such that $AB=BA=I$. If this is the case, then you just note that because $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=I$, then $A$ must be the inverse of $A^{-1}$ so $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$.

Answer (score 1):

For a) if A is invertible, then the column vectors of A are linearly independent.
Buy if Ax = 0 then that would be non trival linear combination of the column vectors summing to 0.

b) If A is invertible then $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A=I$ and $A$ is the inverse of $A^{-1}.$